# Extract client IP address from tcpdump (on OpenBSD)

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to extract and collect some client IP addresses using the command tcpdump, but just can't figure out how to get grep/sed/awk to give me just the first IP address of the output. If I run the following

```
# tcpdump -t -i vlan4 -n  ip dst host 192.168.2
tcpdump: listening on vlan4, link-type EN10MB

tcpdump: WARNING: compensating for unaligned libpcap packets

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: P 3758838950:3758839034..

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: P 84:136(52) ack 117..

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: P 136:188(52) ack 233..

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: . ack 349 win 251 (DF)..
```

I just want to get the first ip on each line without the port number. So from the above output I want to get just.....

```
10.28.6.1

10.28.6.1

10.28.6.1

10.28.6.1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lane '$F[0]=~s/(.*)\..*/$1/g;print $F[0]' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

try this cut line:

```
cut -f1-4 -d "."
```

test with your data:

```
kent$ echo "10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: P 3758838950:3758839034..

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: P 84:136(52) ack 117..

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: P 136:188(52) ack 233..

10.28.6.1.29447 > 192.168.2.62.22: . ack 349 win 251 (DF).."|cut -f1-4 -d "."
10.28.6.1

10.28.6.1

10.28.6.1

10.28.6.1
```